# Is it possible to make a contour plot using ALTAIR 4.1 in python?

Tags: python, contour, altair

I was wondering if there is a way to draw contour plots in altair.

Matplotlib has api for contour plots as demonstrated [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html)

There isn't a dedicated api for contour in Altair [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html)
but i guess may be we could use the grammar to create one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Altair does not support contour plots, because they are not supported in Vega-Lite. The issue that tracks contour support in Vega-Lite can be found here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1919